# Did you ask her yet?

Tags: steganography

Last time I talked to my buddy, Garrick B. Raad, He kept going on about this girl he liked. As we parted ways he mentioned that he was going to ask her out.

A few days went by before I texted him, asking whether he had asked her out yet.

He responded with this: 
[image: generic image description]

Can anyone help me figure out what he said?

Comment: Hm... it's a repeating 5x5 block, but the RGB values don't seem to decode to anything in ASCII...

Comment: It's all in the puzzle :) @Deusovi

Comment: You must have a really weird friend if he responds to a question about a date with a convoluted image puzzle. But hey, that's what Puzzling is all about.

Comment: I keep staring at this trying to get an image to pop out

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As Deusovi pointed out in the comments, it's a repeating 5x5 block, so I focused on those 25 pixels.  The hex values I found for those are

> 620A41746F756820742E6174492E2069206D746768652776752070686E632065647268656E206968207466652065616368207765696C6F2072706C65796C6167696E69204C0A6E6B000000

However, I noticed in the description that

> The buddy's name is Garrick B. Raad - GBR.  While numeric representations of colors are RGB - so he likely rearranged the values to match his name.

After readjusting accordingly, I found that the new hex values were

> 0A41626F757420746861742E2E2049206D696768742776652070756E636865642068657220696E207468652066616365207768696C6520726F6C65706C6179696E67204C696E6B0A000000

Converting that to ASCII, we get

> About that.. I might've punched her in the face while roleplaying Link

Whatever floats your boat, man.

Comment: Nice catch! This definitely is **not** something that happened to a friend, in any way at all

Comment: I think your friend's bigger problem is complicated answers to simple questions :P

Comment: @Areeb Thanks for the clarification.  That answer is in the realm of "[can't make this stuff up](http://definithing.com/you-cant-make-this-stuff-up/)"

Comment: @Kokiomot -- For us lesser mortals, could you please explain (1) How did you (and @Deusovi) determine that the image is a "repeating 5x5 block"? (2) How did you get the RGB values?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps 5x5 refers to the individual pixels in the image.  Zoomed out as it is, the image looks a little like a grid to me.  So I downloaded the image and zoomed in to see the pixels, and noticed that it was a it was a tiled image of 5x5 seemingly random pixels.  From there I cut out all but one tile, and used the eyedropper tool in an image editor to see what the RGB values were for each pixel.